# Parsing XML data in AS3 by attribute

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, xml-parsing, flash-cs6

I am building an application which allows the user to add ingredients in their fridge to a list and then search for all of the potential recipes based on the ingredients they've listed.

I am using XML data which is set out in a fairly simple schema like so:

```
<items>
<item category="meat">chicken</item>
<item category="meat">beef</item>
<item category="vegetable">green beans</item>
</items>
```

The scrolling list part of my app is based on a NetTuts tutorial (http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/create-a-smooth-rolling-scroller-with-as3/). I want to be able to filter my list programatically by XML attributes (i.e. the 'category' attribute above).

Here is my full document class below (I wasn't sure which functions to include to exclude as they all might be important). The functions that you should be aware of are `dataLoaded()` which parses the XML data and puts it into a `TextField` and `dataLoad()` that instantiates the URLLoader object to load the XML. The name of my document class is RecipeMatcher and its constructor is also the same.

I think I've commented it pretty well so there shouldn't be too many question marks over the purpose of variables and functions.

```
package 
{
    ' Imports (All- Unsorted) '
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.Font;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import gs.*;

    public class RecipeMatcher extends MovieClip
    {
        'Variable declaration'
        // ------------------- //
        'Main Structural elements'
        private var _pad:MovieClip;
        public var _addIngredient:MovieClip;
        private var _container:MovieClip;
        'Ingredient Wizard Structural Elements'
        public var _ingredientWizard:MovieClip;
        private var _CollapsePanelMeat:MovieClip;
        private var _CollapsePanelVeg:MovieClip;
        private var _CollapsePanelCarbs:MovieClip;
        private var _CollapsePanelCuisine:MovieClip;
        private var _CollapseMealType:MovieClip;
        private var _CollapseOther:MovieClip;
        'Data (XML) Elements'
        public var loader:URLLoader;
        public var data:XML;
        public var items:XMLList;
        'Positioning of xml data in container - ("Text")'
        private var _item:Item;
        private var _itemTextField:TextField;
        private var _defaultFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        private var _arialRounded:Font = new ArialRounded();
        private var _textFieldXPosition:uint = 10;
        private var _textFieldYPosition:uint = 13; 
        private var _textFieldWidth:uint = 540;
        private var _textFieldPaddingLeft:uint = 20;
        private var _textFieldHeight:uint = 150;
        private var _itemPosition:uint = 49;
        'newIngredientsWizard positioning'
        private var _addNewIngredientsXPosition:uint = 322;
        private var _addNewIngredientsYPosition:uint = 500;
        'input mask - container'
        private var _mask:Shape;
        private var _maskWidth:uint = 580;
        private var _maskHeight:uint = 540;
        private var _paddingTop:uint = 220;
        'background for container '
        private var _background:Shape;
        'scroll speed properties'
        private var _maxSpeed:uint = 15;
        private var _speed:Number;
        'End of variable declarations'
        //----------------------------------//

        //---------Constructor Function---------//
        public function RecipeMatcher()
        {
            'Constructor for the function RecipeMatcher '
            _addIngredient = new addIngredient();
            _ingredientWizard = new ingredientDialog();
            _pad = new Pad();
            addChild(_pad); 
            _ingredientWizard.visible = false;
            _pad.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - _pad.width / 2;
            _pad.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - _pad.height / 2;
            'Event listener for add ingredient button inside of pad movieclip '
            _pad.btn_add.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addNewIngredient);
            _container = new MovieClip();
            addChild(_container);
            dataLoad();
        }

        //-- BEGINNING OF LISTENER FUNCTIONS TO FOOD CATEGORY PAGES - PART OF INGREDIENT WIZARD --//

        function displayMeat(event:MouseEvent):void {
            _ingredientWizard.visible = false;
        }
        function displayVeg(event:MouseEvent):void {
            _ingredientWizard.visible = false;
        }
        function displayCarbs(event:MouseEvent):void {
            _ingredientWizard.visible = false;
        }
        function displayCuisine(event:MouseEvent):void {
            _ingredientWizard.visible = false;
        }
        function displayMealType(event:MouseEvent):void {
            _ingredientWizard.visible = false;
        }
        function displayOther(event:MouseEvent):void {
            _ingredientWizard.visible = false;
        }

        //-- This function is the accompanying function for the event listener in the constructor that listens for clicks on the ingredient items --//

        function itemclicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
            _itemTextField = new TextField();
            trace(_itemTextField.text);
        }
        //-- This function makes all of the elements of the scrolling list invisible, whilst the Add New Ingredients Wizard is displayed to the user //
        function addNewIngredient(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            _pad.visible = false;
            _container.visible = false;
            trace("screen wipe");
            _ingredientWizard = new ingredientDialog();
            addChild(_ingredientWizard);
            _ingredientWizard.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - _ingredientWizard.width / 2;
            _ingredientWizard.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - _ingredientWizard.height / 2;

            _ingredientWizard.collapse_meat.btn_submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, displayMeat);
            _ingredientWizard.collapse_veg.btn_submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, displayVeg);
            _ingredientWizard.collapse_carbs.btn_submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, displayCarbs);
            _ingredientWizard.collapse_cuisine.btn_submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, displayCuisine);
            _ingredientWizard.collapse_mealtype.btn_submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, displayMealType);
            _ingredientWizard.collapse_otherdietarypreferences.btn_submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, displayOther);

            'Submit all ingredient choices button listener'
            _ingredientWizard.btn_submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, submitIngredientChoices);
        }

        function submitIngredientChoices(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("submitted ingredients");

        }
        private function dataLoad():void {
            'instantiates URLLoader object'
            loader = new URLLoader();
            ' listens to see if data has fully loaded'
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataLoaded);
            'loads local xml file with URLrequest method'
            loader.load(new URLRequest("data.xml"));
        }

        private function dataLoaded(event:Event):void {
            ' this holds the loaded xml data '
            data = new XML(event.target.data);
            'items properties call - add other calls to master properties later on'
            items = data.item;
            ' tracing name of all categories in xml doc'
            trace(data.item.@category);
            ' parsing of each ingredient'
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                // instantiation of mcItem (the stage for each item)
                _item = new Item();
                // sets 'over' layer to invisible / transparent //
                _item.item_btn_over.alpha = 0;
                // creates the var itemTextField //
                _itemTextField = new TextField();
                // _itemTextField visual attributes //
                _itemTextField.x = _textFieldXPosition + _textFieldPaddingLeft;
                _itemTextField.y = _textFieldYPosition;
                _itemTextField.selectable = true;
                _itemTextField.wordWrap = true;
                _itemTextField.width = _textFieldWidth;
                _itemTextField.height = _textFieldHeight;
                _itemTextField.embedFonts = true;
                _defaultFormat.color = 0x111112;
                _defaultFormat.font = _arialRounded.fontName;
                _defaultFormat.size = 18;
                _itemTextField.defaultTextFormat = _defaultFormat;
                _itemTextField.text = items[i].toString();
                //adds textfield to displaylist//
                _item.addChild(_itemTextField);
                //vertical positioning//
                _item.y = i * _itemPosition;
                _item.buttonMode = true;
                _item.mouseChildren = false;
                //adds items to container displaylist//
                _container.addChild(_item);
                _item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemclicked);
            }

                ' Input Mask'
                _mask = new Shape();
                _mask.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
                _mask.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, _maskWidth, _maskHeight);
                _mask.graphics.endFill();
                ' Positioning of input mask'
                // horizontal centering of input mask//
                _mask.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - _container.width / 2;
                _mask.y = _paddingTop;
                // adds the mask onto the stage//
                addChild(_mask);
                // assigns the above mask to the container //
                _container.mask = _mask;
                ' Positioning of container with the mask'
                // horizontal centering of container //
                _container.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - _container.width / 2;
                // vertical position of container //
                _container.y = _paddingTop;

                'Container background stylings'
                _background = new Shape();
                _background.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
                _background.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, _container.width, _container.height);
                _background.graphics.endFill();
                _container.addChildAt(_background, 0);
                'End of container background stylings'

                _container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, movingOver);
                _container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, movingOut);
            }

            'function: movingOver (MOUSE_OVER) EVENT '
            private function movingOver (event:MouseEvent):void {
                _container.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, movingOver);
                addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
                if (event.target is Item)
                TweenMax.to(Item(event.target).item_btn_over, .2, {alpha:1});
            }
            'function: movingOut (MOUSE_OUT) EVENT '
            private function movingOut (event:MouseEvent):void {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
                _container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, movingOver);
                if (event.target is Item)
                TweenMax.to(Item(event.target).item_btn_over, .2, {alpha:0});
            }
            'ENTER_FRAME listener function to gauge scrolling speed based on touch / mouse position + events'
            function enterFrame(event:Event):void {
                _speed = (_mask.height / 2 - _mask.mouseY) / (_mask.height / 2) * _maxSpeed;
                _container.y += _speed;
                if (_container.y >= _paddingTop) {
                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
                    _container.y = _paddingTop;
                }
                if (_container.y <= _mask.height - _container.height + _paddingTop) {
                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
                    _container.y = _mask.height - _container.height + _paddingTop;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answerers, feel free to edit my code down to a manageable size once you have highlighted the functions that are necessary.

EDIT: I have managed to find this snippet of code on the internet as you can see in my code, but it only lists the actual categories themselves rather than all items in the category. I'm not good enough at AS3 to go any further.

```
 ' tracing name of all categories in xml doc'
            trace(data.item.@category);
```

Comment: Comments in ActionScript are denoted by starting a line with `//` or enclosing within `/*` and `*/`.  Your use of VB.NET style comments does not throw a compiler error, but embed numerous string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must search by next line:

```
const lookingCategoryName : String = "meat";
const findedItemsXMLList : XMLList = data.item.(@category == lookingCategoryName);
trace(findedItemsXMLList.toXMLString());
```